# Join two tables from database and display one column values in dropdown list in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the below query.
I want to join two tables and display the one column in the drop-down list.

The controller code:

```
// GET: SelectLLD
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var sLoginName = Session["LoginName"];
    var iLoginId = Session["LoginID"];

    if(sLoginName!= null)
    {
        ViewBag.LoginId = iLoginId;


        //Db context object 
        enterpriseEntities db = new enterpriseEntities();

        var lob = from l in db.Lobs
                  join r in db.Rights
                  on l.LobID equals r.LobID
                  //where r.LoginID =
                  select new
                  {
                      l.LobName

                  };
        SelectList list = new SelectList (lob, "lobname");

        ViewBag.LobNames = list;
        return View();

    }
    else{

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }


}
```

The view Code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h4>Welcome @Session["LoginName"]</h4>
<h4>@ViewBag.LoginId</h4>
<h3>Select LOB</h3>

<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("LobNames", "Select a Value")
</div>
<h3>Select Bussiness Date </h3>
```

The problem is that with the above code I an getting the column name also added with the column value in the drop-down list.
Below is the screen shot

I am getting the out having column name and the value.
[image: i am getting the out having column name and the value]

I want only the column values to be displayed in the drop-down. For example only the "Sales" value should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you change the `SelectList list = new SelectList (lob, "lobname");` code to something like this?

```
  var list = logb.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
            Value = x.LobID.ToString(),
            Text = x.LobName
        }).ToList();
```

This would mean you have have to add the `LobId` to original select like so

```
var lob = from l in db.Lobs
                  join r in db.Rights
                  on l.LobID equals r.LobID
                  //where r.LoginID =
                  select new
                  {
                      LobName = l.LobName,
                      LobID = L.LobID
                  };
```

EDIT: This is assuming you want the LobID value to be passed if you submit the form and not the LobName.

Comment: Thank you very much Bad it working as expected i needed lob name in the drop down list i have modified the code accordingly